# Scala Curly braces with and without return statement

Tags: scala, if-statement, return, expression, curly-braces

I am trying to understand the basics of scala curly braces and with/without return statement.

```
def method(a:Int):Int = {
           if(a == 10 ) 10
           if(a == 11 ) {11}
           if(a == 12 ) { return 12 }
           if(a == 13 ) return {13}
           1}
```

| Method Call | Output |
| --- | --- |
| method(10) | **1** |
| method(11) | **1** |
| method(12) | 12 |
| method(13) | 13 |

From the above we can note that

- the output of calls to method(12) & method(13) are as expected.
- Whereas the output of calls to **method(10) & method(11)** we see the value returned is **1** which is confusing given **return** keyword is **not required** for scala.

Another thing I noted was that :

```
def method(a:Int) = {
           if(a == 10 ) 10
           if(a == 11 ) {11}
           if(a == 12 ) {12}
           if(a == 13 )  {13}
           }
```

| Method Call | Output |
| --- | --- |
| method(10) | **()** |
| method(11) | **()** |
| method(12) | **()** |
| method(13) | 13 |

The above two method statements seems confusing.
Kindly help to clarify the above why there is difference in values returned.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curly braces are irrelevant in this code; they can all be omitted without any effect on the result.

As far as `return` goes, do not use it unless you know what it does (which isn't what you think it does).

The value of a function is the value of the last expression in the function, so you need to make the `if` statements into a single `if`/`else` expression:

```
def method(a: Int) = 
       if (a == 10) 10
       else if(a == 11) 11
       else if(a == 12) 12
       else if(a == 13) 13
       else 1
```

In practice a `match` is a better choice for this sort of code.